# how to list and operate on certain subset of class methods maybe

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an es6 class with some methods on it `this.OnGame`, I have to glue it together with some other code:

How can I simplify this, glue, piece of code:

```
class Gluer {
  glueBaby() {
     this.addSomeGlue('method1');
     this.addSomeGlue('method2');
     this.addSomeGlue('method3');
     this.addSomeGlue('method4');
     this.addSomeGlue('method5');
     this.addSomeGlue('method6');
  }

  addSomeGlue(fn) {
    var game = this.game;

    game.client[fn] = this.OnGame[fn].bind(this.OnGame);
  }
}
```

I want some dry code, to add some functions (regex matched ones), from `this.OnGame` to `game.client`.

Comment: Do you have any problem with this code? What exactly you want?

Comment: I want to get rid of this glue, and make it automated, maybe doesn't worth the effort though.

Comment: You want all the functions in `OnGame` to be added to the `game.client`?

Comment: some methods, maybe a regex is needed. @thefourtheye

Comment: Please include all these information in the question, also a sample class with the expected result.

Comment: Your `Gluer` class instances neither seems to have a `.game` nor a `.OnGame` property? Where do those come from? Please provide a complete example.

Comment: What does this question have to do with ES6? Are there some specific ES6 features your gluer need to support?